# c#: string(json) to object(generic) conversion adds extra braces

Tags: c#, json

I have a json as string. I want to convert it into an object. But during conversion, everything is fine, except i get an extra braces outside of the object. That is not a valid json.

```
string st = "{\"Category\":\"test\"}";
var someType = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(st);
//output of someType is {{"Category": "test"}}
//expected output {"Category": "test"}
```

I tried "JObject.Parse()" too. But the result is the same. It adds extra braces to the object.
I want the output as an object compulsorily.

Is there anything that i'm doing wrong? Am i missing something?

Comment: what do you mean by "output of someType is ....". How are you trying to output it ?

Comment: what you have try to achieve here, you want your desired output at compile time or run time? bcoz runtime its gives you like `{"Category": "test"}`

Comment: @Pac0, I was checking the value of the variable in debug mode

Comment: @ershoaib I want to pass this object to another function. But it is being passed with extra braces like this {{"Category": "test"}}

Comment: @SinuJoseph, could you plz add that `another function` to your question? so i get an idea to resolve your problem asap :)

Comment: I am using ClosedXML(https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML.Report) in my project. It generates Excel report given an excel template. To generate the report, it requires Template(in excel) and a json object(passed from the above).

Comment: @SinuJoseph, yes your right here but until i see your use of json to `another function` then i m unable to help you

Comment: `string st = "{\"Category\":\"test\"}";
var someType = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(st);
var template = new XLTemplate(templatePath);
template.AddVariable("test", someType);
template.Generate();`

template.Generate throws error, because it receives an invalid json having {{"Category": "test"}}

Comment: @SinuJoseph, so are u getting any error when u pass double curly braced json to `template.AddVariable`?

Comment: No. at template.Generate() it throws the following error: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty' does not contain a definition for 'Item''

Comment: i m not sure but i think your `template.Generate()` method doesn't find `Item` property that it want. you can pass `string` to `template.AddVariable` bcoz it also accept `string` so try this => `string st = "{\"Category\":\"test\"}";
            JObject jObject1 = JObject.Parse(st);
            string s = jObject1.ToString();` and pass `s` to `template.AddVariable`

Comment: No. I need to pass it as an object. If i pass it as string, excel prints the entire value as string

Comment: @SinuJoseph, try to replace `Category` with `Item` in your json and pass your `JObject` to `template.AddVariable`

Comment: @SinuJoseph,  like => `string st = "{\"Item\":\"test\"}"; JObject jObject1 = JObject.Parse(st);`

Comment: It still throws the same error Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty' does not contain a definition for 'Item''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of what you're asking, `JsonConver.DeserializeObject(st)` is doing exactly what you're asking it to do.  You're asking it to convert a string representation of the "object" `{"Category": "test"}` to a json object.  The problem with your approach, is that the compiler does not know how to interpret that string as anything other than an object, so it wraps it in a JSON object.

To get the result you're looking for, without declaring a POCO (i.e. deserializing an anonymous type), you'd need to do something like this

```
    var definition = new { Category = "" };
    var data = @"{'Category':'Test'}";
    var me = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(data, definition);
    Console.WriteLine(me);
```

Adding another solution, given what was asked for in the comments.

```
    dynamic deserialized = JObject.Parse("{\"Category\":\"test\"}");
```

Comment: I'd like to add, as a caveat, that this is not a preferable solution, overall.  It'd be far more ideal to add a POCO that defines the mapping for your JsonConvert call.  It'd be much better to call JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T> with a defined type.

Comment: the problem is that, the definition of  "data"  is not fixed. Is there any way where i can achieve the output like this? {"Category": "test"}

Comment: Can I convert the definition from string value? I will store "{Category = ""}" in the database. Can i assign it to `var definition`?

Comment: Even the JObject.Parse is giving an ouput like {{
  "Category": "test"
}}

Comment: How will i write definition for `{
  'CATEGORY': 'A',
  'Reports': [
    {
      'Report_id': '1',
      'REPORT_NAME': 'TEST1',
      'REPORT_TYPE': 'PUBLISH'
    },
    {
      'Report_id': '2',
      'REPORT_NAME': 'TEST2',
      'REPORT_TYPE': 'DAILY'
    },
    {
      'Report_id': '3',
      'REPORT_NAME': 'TEST3',
      'REPORT_TYPE': 'MONTHLY'
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: It depends on how your data is taken, as input... Is it a string of json that you want to parse to a C# object?  Somewhere along the line, to do anything with the data, you're going to need to get some amount of description of the object...  As far as your question about the above string of json, this works fine: dynamnic parsedJson = JObject.Parse("{your_definition}");  After this, you'll need to know some details about the object to read any data off of it. Dynamic allows indexing, so parsedJson["property_name"] works.